# UIAlertView error outside of the bounds of the array of a text field but not using textfields

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I'm using the `UIAlertView` but I get the following error message:

* Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'textFieldIndex (0) is outside of the bounds of the array of text fields'

However there are not `textFields` in my `UIAlertView` and I never access them somewhere...

This is my code:

```
alertNewVersion = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Update"
                                            message: @"There is a new version"
                                            delegate: self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel",nil];
[alertNewVersion setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleDefault];
alertNewVersion.tag = 1;
[alertNewVersion show];
```

However when I change the "`delegate:self`" to "`delegate:nil`" it doesn't crash with the error but ofcourse my delegate functions don't work then... Any idea how the problem could be?

**EDIT:**

Second UIAlertView:

```
- (IBAction)startPushed:(id)sender {

    message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test."
                                        message:nil
                                        delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
    [[message textFieldAtIndex:1] setSecureTextEntry:NO];
    [[message textFieldAtIndex:0] setPlaceholder:@"xx"];
    [[message textFieldAtIndex:1] setPlaceholder:@"xxx"];
    message.tag = 2;
    [message show];

}
```

Delegate method:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {


if(alertView.tag == 1){ // alertNewVersion
    if (buttonIndex == 0) { //button "OK" clicked
       NSLog(@"test");
    }

}

if(alertView.tag == 2){ // Message

    if (buttonIndex == 0) { //button "OK" clicked
        NSString *Name = [[message textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:Name forKey:@"xx"]; 

        NSString *Class = [[message textFieldAtIndex:1] text];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:Class forKey:@"xxx"]; 
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Well, obviously, the problem is in your delegate function.  Why don't you show what you are doing there?  I bet you are using textFieldWithIndex

Comment: please post the code where app crashed...

Comment: I commented out everything in the delegate function so its empty...

Comment: i think you used morethan one alertview in this same class right??

Comment: maybe you are trying to make some UIView modifications by tag somewhere in your implementation, and tag of UIAlertView and it's textField is like some other element's tag?

Comment: No, I commeneted out the "alertNewVersion.tag = 1" and still got the same error, I don't use it anywhere actually

Comment: please post the method clickedButtonAtIndex of alertView delegate method...

Comment: I do use more than one alertview in this class and the other one got textField inputs but I commeneted it out cleaned and rebuild and it still gives me the same eror

Comment: Add a breakpoint on throw exception. This should give you the exact line where it crashes.

Comment: @Mar0ux yes its important that where it crashed but i think this crashed in clickedButtonAtIndex delegate method of UIAlertView bcoz when he remove delegate to self and set nil at that time its working otherwise its crahsed what you think??\

Comment: @ParasJoshi Can you point to the exact line where it crashes? Also, I'm unclear if you have 2 alert views or not? In the first line you state you don't have any textFields, but your delegate does access textFields.

Comment: @Mar0ux see here nonuma uses 2 alertview in which one alertview is Default and other is with textfields so whenever its delegate method called and find its textfield from its array with this line.. textFieldAtIndex:0 at that time it crahsed that alertview have not any textfield(out of bounds) like NSArray.. :)

Comment: You're obviously saving UIAlertView instances, did you try `alertView == message` instead of `alertView.tag == 2`? Also, try printing alertView.alertViewStyle in your delegate to see if you're getting the right instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here set different `tag` to every `UIAlertView` and use bellow code...

You get error because here when you use your  `alertNewVersion` `UIAlertView` at that time its go to found the textField at 0 index and here it have not Array of `UITextFields` and application crashed here so use bellow condition...

**UPDATE:**

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (alertView.tag == 1) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
           /// do nothing here
        }
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == 2){
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
       if([title isEqualToString:@"Ok"])
       {
           UITextField *txtName = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
           UITextField *txtClass = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
           NSLog(@"Name: %@\nClass: %@", txtName.text, txtClass.text);
       }
    }

}
```

use this code instead fo your first above code...

```
UIAlertView *alt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Update" message:@"There is a new version" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
alt.tag = 1;
[alt show];
[alt release];
```

And For Message see this bellow code...

```
//show alertview for message
- (IBAction)startPushed:(id)sender {
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test."
                                                      message:nil
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];



    [message setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput];
    UITextField *text1 = [message textFieldAtIndex:0];
    text1.placeholder=@"xxx";
    [[message textFieldAtIndex:1] setSecureTextEntry:NO];
    UITextField *text2= [message textFieldAtIndex:1];
    text2.placeholder=@"xxx";
    message.tag = 2;
    [message show];
}
```

Comment: @nonuma also you added UIAlertViewDelegate in .h file?? check that

Comment: Yes I did, since the UIAlertView with the textFields input work, its just when I add the normal UIAlertView it gives me the error...

Comment: seee i updated my answer just use that code instead of you alloc alertNewVersion alertView.. and i am sure dude that its problem and crashed in clickedButtonAtIndex ..

Comment: I copied your answer in my project instead of mine but as I said its still the same error even if I commented out the other alertview and commented out the whole alertView delegate method

Comment: it must worked dude.. try to change some different tags like set 111 or 222 tag... i used many alertview in 1 class and its works like above...

Comment: @nonuma i Update my whole answer try out this now and let me know.. :) hope its will helpful to you... :)

Comment: anyone checked on real device? it works on ios8 perfect but get crashed on ios7

Comment: @GajendraKChauhan It was working at that time. Now I've not iOS 7.0 is available. but I'll check it and let you know.

Answer (score 2):

In below method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

Give your alert view name & do what ever you want like below:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{ 

    if(alertView == alertNewVersion)
    { 
    }   
    if(alertView == message)
    { 
    } 
}
```